# Robocopy Hangs / Gets Stuck - Move to Next File Command/Timer?

Tags: freeze, robocopy, xcopy, copy

I have an issue when I utilize Robocopy. I have a fairly homogeneous directory and I am trying to move it from one drive to another. The drive where the files reside must be corrupted. I would ideally like to begin the copy process and if it sticks on any file for more than "x" seconds, move onto copying the next. At this time if I begin to copy the progress of a file may hang at 30% for 10 minutes before getting to /R:0 and failing due to retry limit.

It would be more preferable if there were a way to go to copy file 1, if it copies <20 seconds great! Else, if it does not copy <20 seconds move to next.

Any way to do this either w/ robocopy or another script?

Thanks so much

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy scans the target folder first to determine if it is creating or updating files.  With huge file lists this takes can take minutes with nothing apparently happening.  Be patient, the actual copy/move will start.

If the target directory is empty the copy starts immediately.